# get record with no children in hierarchical Tables sql server

Tags: sql-server

hi i have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[personel2](
[prsl_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ,
[prsl_name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[prsl_family] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[parent_id] [int] NULL)
```

and `prsl_id` is primary key and `parent_id` is foreign key that have relation ship to `prsl_id`.
i have a big problem , how can i find records **that have no children** in this table ? 
for example :

```
 prsl_id|parent_id|name               
 1      |null     |a
 2      |1        |b        
 3      |null     |c
 4      |2        |d
```

expected result is :

```
prsl_id|parent_id|name               
 3      |null     |c
 4      |2        |d
```

please help me soon as possible . thanks ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT x.prsl_id from 

(SELECT e.prsl_id,  COUNT(s.prsl_id) as "Num_subordinates"
FROM   dbo.personel2 e
       LEFT JOIN dbo.personel2 s ON s.prsl_id = e.parent_id
GROUP  BY e.prsl_id) x where Num_subordinates = 0
```

You can try this for your issue

```
select prsl_id from personel2 x where not exists (select parent_id from personel2 y where x.prsl_id=y.parent_id)
```

Comment: it did not give me correct result . i add an example in my first question , and ur code give me this result :**prsl_id{1,3}** , the result must be prsl_id :{3,4}

Comment: Please try select prsl_id from personel2 x  where  not  exists (select parent_id from personel2 y where x.prsl_id=y.parent_id)

Comment: can u please give me complete code i am beginner in sql .where i must place the select? and there is another problem i need to show all fields...

Comment: Have edited the answer. You can check if it gives you the desired output now. If you need all fields , you need to use a '*' after select